# StatusCode":"DFExecutorUserError","Message":"Job failed due to reason: at Source 'x'(Line 1/Col 0)

Tags: azure, etl, azure-data-factory

I am new to Azure Data Factory and I build my first pipeline but I am having the below error that does not really tells me much? I tried googling it but not much luck...

```
Operation on target dataPracticeFlow failed: {"StatusCode":"DFExecutorUserError","Message":"Job failed due to reason: at Source 'x'(Line 1/Col 0): Limit should be integer value greater than 0","Details":""}
```

Please can someone try to point me in the wright direction?

Answer (score 0):

This error can be caused due to many reasons. It could be caused due to source columns or data types. Verify source columns/parameters/data types if any value passed where integer value is expected.

If the issue persists, you can raise a support ticket for the support engineer to investigate more on the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I Had the same problem,
I fixed it by **remove all cast operations from my data flow.**

The Data types should match from sink to source.